# How to display remaining table in a 'DIV inside table'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is structure of table with Colgroup:

```
<div class="pure-g">
  <table border='0' style='width: 100%;' class='pure-table pure-table-bordered'>
    <colgroup>
      <col width='10%'>
      <col width='82%'>
      <col width='20%'>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
       <th>Nr</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <div id="Report"> //Here i will display remaining table
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

In Javascript, I am creating remaining rows and inserting it using:

```
$('#Report').html(tableStructure);
```

But when table is displayed:  jumps out from Table tag and sits above table tag. Means dynamically created table is created above table/heading. Any suitable way to achieve that inside div only?

Comment: You want to display the table inside table or you want to create new dynamic rows.

Comment: You cannot use <div> inside <table>

Comment: You need to put the <div> inside a table cell, and the cell inside a row tag.

Comment: `<tr><td><div id="Report"></div></td></tr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a `div` directly inside a `table` like this. Tables can only contain:

1. Optional `<caption>`.
2. Zero of more `<colgroup>`.
3. Optional `<thead>`.
4. Optional `<tfoot>`.
5. Zero or more `<tbody>`, or else zero or more `<tr>` (which are treated as being in a single implicit `<tbody>`.

As of HTML 5, `<tfoot>` can also appear at the end, instead of before the first `<tbody>`.

`<div>` is not in that list, and when you put one there the browser did the best it could in rendering both the div and the table, in putting it outside the table. However, there's no reason why you can't do:

```
<div class="pure-g">
  <table border='0' style='width: 100%;' class='pure-table pure-table-bordered'>
    <colgroup>
      <col width='10%'>
      <col width='82%'>
      <col width='20%'>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nr</th>
        <th scope="col">Question</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Report"> //Here i will display remaining table
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me with charm. No external adjustments of width required. Simply put the data in. Thanks:)

Comment: It's worth learning the rules about just which elements are allowed to go where (and worth learning both the pre- and post-HTML5 rules, which changed a lot). While generally breaking those rules is something you can get away with in practice, there are some cases like here where you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea about colgroup, but as for your jQuery, you should be appending to the table, not changing the html of the #report div. assuming your table is within your report div - append it like thus:

```
$('#Report>table').append(tableStructure);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a structure like this:

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <table border='0' style='width: 100%;' class='pure-table pure-table-bordered'>
        <colgroup>
            <col width='10%'>
            <col width='82%'>
            <col width='20%'>
        </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>Nr</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="Report"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

[jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/466h7a26/)

**Updated:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="pure-g">
        <table border='0' style='width: 100%;' class='pure-table pure-table-bordered'>
            <colgroup>
                <col width='10%'>
                <col width='82%'>
                <col width='20%'>
            </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>Nr</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div id="Report"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var tablerStructure = "<table style='width=100%'><tr>";
$("colgroup col").each(function() {
    tablerStructure += "<td width='" + $(this).width() + "'>This table structure is inserted via javascript</td>";
});
tablerStructure += "</tr></table>";
$('#Report').append(tablerStructure);
```

**css**

```
#Report {
    width: 100%
}
#Report table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/466h7a26/1/

Comment: But it is not picking Col Width which have define above.